# Is there a function where you can convert a template into a string of HTML? (Laravel Blade)

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

Is there a function where you can convert a template into a string of HTML, then store it to string in controller?

for Rails, like "render_to_string" on a template with dynamic vars.

Comment: this is for https://htmlcsstoimage.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rendered = view(...)->render();
```

Views have a `render` method.